# Remove custom post type slug from URL and add taxonomy Slug

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting

I am having an issue while changing a custom post type URL. Current post type URL is:

```
http://example.com/product/product-slug
```

where product is a custom post type.

I want to change it to:

```
http://domain.com/brand/brand-slug/product-slug
```

where brand is the custom taxonomy.

I found code that removes `/product/` from the custom post type URL and it's working fine for me. I am using following code.

```
function gp_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'gp_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );


function gp_parse_request_trick( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'product' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gp_parse_request_trick' );
```

Permalink setting is `/%postname%/`. But when I am changing the permalink setting to `/brand/%brand%/%postname%/`, all the custom post types start giving me 404 error.

Please suggest what changes need to be done in the above code to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: I used this plugin, but I have more then 5000 product that's automatically adding and removing. So I don't have time for manually change each product. Later on I will have more then 15000 product, that will be automatically add, so I don't want any manual work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up simple tax/cpt permalinks with the `rewrite` argument when you register the post type:

```
function wpd_product_brand_types() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'brand',
        'product',
        array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'brand', 'with_front' => false )
        )
    );

    register_post_type(
        'product',
        array(
            'label' => 'Products',
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'brand/%brand%', 'with_front' => false )
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init','wpd_product_brand_types' );
```

Then the `post_type_link` filter swaps in the `%brand%` slug:

```
function wpd_product_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'brand' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%brand%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_product_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Comment: I applied this solution, but all the custom type post redirecting to 404 error page.

Comment: @user2504941 did you flush permalinks after changing them?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that.

Comment: update your question with the complete code you are currently using.